# Solr preserve whitspace search

Tags: solr

Below is my fieldtype and I want to preserve the white space during search

```
 <fieldType name="searchterm" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="250" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

So example: input  = "alpha beta" and I search for either "alpha" ,"beta" will match, but how do I enforce the non match for a search term like "alpha eta" (which should not match). I should also match for "eta","pha" but not "alpha eta"

Comment: does "alpha eta" actually match?

Comment: Maybe shingle filters? `-shingled_text_field:alpha eta`

Comment: @FridayChils: yes with the above FilterType alpha eta matches on alpha

Comment: what is the -shingled_text_field?

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to know what kind of application needs such a search :-).

You can do the following:

- if your search term has no spaces, use your existing field `searchterm`.
- to help with search queries that have space(s) in them, create a new [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) (say called `newsearchterm`) which uses [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) instead of NGramFilterFactory.

For `newsearchterm` the analysis will happen this way:

`alpha beta` ==> `alp`, `alph`, `alpha`, `bet`, `beta`

so a search `newsearchterm:(alpha AND eta)` won't match `alpha beta`.